# Repeated column in PHP

Tags: php

```
$course = mysql_query('SELECT cc.name, c.fullname FROM mdl_course WHERE cc.id = c.id');

echo '<table>';
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($course))
{
     $categoryname = $row['name'];
     $coursename   = $row['fullname'];
     echo '<tr><td>$categoryname</td>
               <td>$coursename</td>
           </tr>
}
echo '</table>';
```

I want the category name to display only once  i.e, it shouldn't repeat

Comment: Please explain exactly what this outputs at the moment, and why you think it is currently "repaeating". Also, questions usually have a `?` in them somewhere.

Comment: Your query `SELECT cc.name, c.fullname FROM mdl_course WHERE cc.id = c.id` isnt valid - there do you define the table aliases `cc` and `c` ?

Answer (score 2):

Some possible answers are already given. My idea was to keep a counter variable too to check and see if it is the first iteration. If so, then show the category name.

But besides of that i really think you should re-check your database design. Why does multiple rows have the same category name? That is wrong in terms of database design. The category should be in a sepparate table.

That way you can loop through the categories first, echo the category name, then loop through the mdl_course table and get all the rows where the pk_category_id equals the fk_category_id from the mdl_course table.

Example:

```
$cats = query ("SELECT pk_category_id, name FROM categories");
while ( $cat_row = mysql_fetch_row($cats) )
{
    echo $cat_row['name'];

    $cats = query ("SELECT cols, you, need FROM mdl_course WHERE fk_category_id = '".$cat_row['pk_category_id']."'");
    while ( $mdl_row = mysql_fetch_row($cats) )
    {
        echo 'other data';
    }
}
```

Comment: The braces do not match. It is not clear wether the second loop is to run inside the first or after the first has finished. I would recommend against using $cats for both result sets. Also, looping one after another means you couldn't display the correct courses next to their categories, looping one inside the other gives quite some overhead.

Comment: @Inca The second loop is inside the other, the last bracket just falls out of the code tag for some reason. And besides, nested loops don't cause overhead. Don't know where you got that nonsense. Especially not in this case.

Comment: fixed the indentation. The nested loops don't cause overhead, the repeated querying (which would be the number of categories, +1 outer query) usually does. But you are correct, I should have worded that better.

Answer (score 1):

You should add a temp var to save the previous category name, and print it only if it has changed. 
*Note: this solution assumes your query results are grouped by **categoryname***

Like this:

```
$course = mysql_query('SELECT cc.name, c.fullname FROM mdl_course WHERE cc.id = c.id');

echo '<table>';
$prev_name = ''; //temp var
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($course))
{
     $categoryname = $row['name'];
     $coursename   = $row['fullname'];
     echo '<tr><td>'.($prev_name != $categoryname ? $categoryname : '').'</td>
               <td>$coursename</td>
           </tr>';
     $prev_name = $categoryname; //temp var assignment
}
echo '</table>';
```

this snippet will check if the category name has changed, and give an appropriate output (the new category name or an empty string):

```
($prev_name != $categoryname ? $categoryname : '')
```

Comment: Also what if the results are repeated but not contiguous? This would not catch that...

Comment: You're right. I'll edit the answer so it's clear that I'm assuming the results are grouped by category name.

Comment: Thank You MeLight, I got the solution as you guided.

Comment: Ordered by, not grouped by, I presume? (If grouped, you don't have access to the individual courses.)

Comment: Yah. Can you tell I don't do databases a lot? ;)